# R: aggregate with column-specific function

Tags: r, aggregate

I would like to aggregate a data frame by time interval, applying a different function to each column. I think I almost have `aggregate` down, and have divided my data into intervals with the `chron` package, which was easy enough.

But I'm not sure how to process the subsets. All of the mapping functions, `*apply`, `*ply`, take one function (I was hoping for something that took a vector of functions to apply per-column or -variable, but haven't found one) so I'm writing a function that takes my data frame subsets, and gives me the mean for all variables, except "time", which is the index, and "Runoff" which should be the sum.

I tried this:

```
aggregate(d., list(Time=trunc(d.$time, "00:10:00")), function (dat) with(dat, 
list(Time=time[1], mean(Port.1), mean(Port.1.1), mean(Port.2), mean(Port.2.1), 
mean(Port.3), mean(Port.3.1), mean(Port.4), mean(Port.4.1), Runoff=sum(Port.5))))
```

which would be ugly enough even if it didn't give me this error:

```
Error in eval(substitute(expr), data, enclos = parent.frame()) : 
  not that many frames on the stack
```

which tells me I'm really doing something wrong. From what I've seen of R I think there must be an elegant way to do this, but what is it?

dput:

```
d. <- structure(list(time = structure(c(15030.5520833333, 15030.5555555556, 
15030.5590277778, 15030.5625, 15030.5659722222), format = structure(c("m/d/y", 
"h:m:s"), .Names = c("dates", "times")), origin = structure(c(1, 
1, 1970), .Names = c("month", "day", "year")), class = c("chron", 
"dates", "times")), Port.1 = c(0.359747, 0.418139, 0.417459, 
0.418139, 0.417459), Port.1.1 = c(1.3, 11.8, 11.9, 12, 12.1), 
    Port.2 = c(0.288837, 0.335544, 0.335544, 0.335544, 0.335544
    ), Port.2.1 = c(2.3, 13, 13.2, 13.3, 13.4), Port.3 = c(0.253942, 
    0.358257, 0.358257, 0.358257, 0.359002), Port.3.1 = c(2, 
    12.6, 12.7, 12.9, 13.1), Port.4 = c(0.352269, 0.410609, 0.410609, 
    0.410609, 0.410609), Port.4.1 = c(5.9, 17.5, 17.6, 17.7, 
    17.9), Port.5 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), .Names = c("time", 
"Port.1", "Port.1.1", "Port.2", "Port.2.1", "Port.3", "Port.3.1", 
"Port.4", "Port.4.1", "Port.5"), row.names = c(NA, 5L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are a lot of things wrong with your approach. A general piece of advice is not to go straight for what you think the final statement should look like, but work things in increments, otherwise it makes debugging (understanding and fixing errors) quite hard.

For example, you could have started with:

```
aggregate(d., list(Time=trunc(d.$time, "00:10:00")), identity)
```

to notice that there is something wrong with your split variable. Apparently `aggregate` does not like working with this class of data. You can fix this problem by converting `Time` to numeric:

```
aggregate(d., list(Time=as.numeric(trunc(d.$time, "00:10:00"))), identity)
```

Then you can try

```
aggregate(d., list(Time=as.numeric(trunc(d.$time, "00:10:00"))), apply.fun)
```

where `apply.fun` is your user-defined function. This fails with a rather criptic message, but running

```
aggregate(d., list(Time=as.numeric(trunc(d.$time, "00:10:00"))), print)
```

helps realize that the `FUN` function inside `aggregate` is not called once for each data piece (and passed a data.frame), but it is called once for each column of your data pieces (and passed an unnamed vector), so there is no way you can get the result you want using `aggregate`.

Instead, you could use the `ddply` function from the `plyr` package. There, the function applied to each piece does receive a data.frame so you can do something like this:

```
apply.fun <- function(dat) with(dat, data.frame(Time=time[1],
                                                mean(Port.1),
                                                mean(Port.1.1),
                                                mean(Port.2),
                                                mean(Port.2.1),
                                                mean(Port.3),
                                                mean(Port.3.1),
                                                mean(Port.4),
                                                mean(Port.4.1),
                                                Runoff=sum(Port.5)))

d.$Time <- as.numeric(trunc(d.$time, "00:10:00"))
library(plyr)
ddply(d., "Time", apply.fun)

#            Time mean.Port.1. mean.Port.1.1. mean.Port.2. mean.Port.2.1.
# 1 15030.5520833    0.4061886           9.82    0.3262026          11.04
#   mean.Port.3. mean.Port.3.1. mean.Port.4. mean.Port.4.1. Runoff
# 1     0.337543          10.66     0.398941          15.32      0
```

**Edit:** Follow-up on @roysc question in the first comment below, you can do:

```
apply.fun <- function(dat) {
  out <- as.data.frame(lapply(dat, mean))
  out$Time <- dat$time[1]
  out$Runoff <- sum(dat$Port.5)
  return(out)
}
```

Comment: okay, I think I understand this a little better. I'm used to strongly typed languages and find R's class-coercion scheme confusing. What I'd also like to know is if there's a simple way to take the mean of most colums, but treat one specially, without doing it explicitly. Will I have to separate the df and then recombine the columns?

Answer (score 5):

Use `by` instead of `aggregate`.

If `f` is the samee as your anonymous function except that `list` within it is replaced with `data.frame` so that `f <- function(dat) with(dat, data.frame(...whatever...))` then:

```
d.by <- by(d., list(Time = trunc(d.$time, "00:10:00")), f)
d.rbind <- do.call("rbind", d.by) # bind rows together

# fix up row and column names
rownames(d.rbind) <- NULL
colnames(d.rbind) <- colnames(d.)
```

We could remove the last statement which assigns column names if `f` added the names itself rather than just `Time`.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
library(plyr)
ddply(d., .(time), colMeans)
```

Comment: this misses the fact that one of the column is not supposed to have the mean, but rather the sum

Comment: I noticed that but more useful answers came around. I'll update this.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use a sequence of steps that will accomplish the same task in base R by alternately running aggregate() then using merge() as in:

```
agMeans_df <- aggregate(cbind(Port.1,Port1.1,Port.2,Port.2.2,Port.3,Port.3.1,Port.4,Port4.1)~timevar,data=d,mean)
agSum_df <- aggregate(Port.5~timevar,data=d,sum)
ag_all_df <- merge(agMeans_df,agSum_df,by="timevar")
```

I glossed over the issues raised in other responses that the group vector needs to be of the right class (here "timevar"), and that ordering of the columns may be changed. Some renaming prior to the merge() will also be required if you want to run several different functions on the *same* column to avoid confusing two aggregated columns that have the same names.